# Javascript code works on IE but fails on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

This code works fine on IE, but fails on Chrome.

**Theory:** When you click on the input, the input marks with an X or when you hit again the X is deleted (just like a checkbox) , when any of these conditions are met, the script should send the forms Y ( if X is checked) or N (if X is empty ).

### HTML

**Note:** The values are generated dynamically using the data from a external database).

```
<input type="text" READONLY id="65535" class="chk" iffalse="N" iftrue="Y" value=""
    onclick="fchkboxclick();" />
```

### JavaScript

```
function fchkboxclick() {
    object = window.event.srcElement;
    if (object.id == '65535') {
        if (object.value == 'X') {
            activevalue = object.getAttribute("iffalse");
            objet.value = '';
        } else {
            activevalue = object.getAttribute("iftrue");
            object.value = 'X';
        }
    } else {
        if (object.value == 'X') {
            sendevent(object.id, 'check', object.getAttribute("iffalse"));
        } else {
            sendevent(object.id, 'check', object.getAttribute("iftrue"));
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this on any version of IE, the forms (sendevent function) receive the value from the attribute (Y or N) but in Chrome I just receive X.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `srcElement` is last used in IE8, in modern browsers it's `target`. Notice, that this will also fail in FF, you have to pass `event` from the inline call.

Comment: also, window.event is IE specific - which is why this code is IE specific

Comment: @JaromandaX Chrome has implemented that too.

Comment: @Teemu firefox hasn't - chrome is busy trying to follow other browsers leads (even 15 year old ones) it seems

Comment: @JaromandaX Yep, that's why I've mentioned this problem in my first comment.

Comment: yes, that's not the point in the code. at least i think so. And this is from an internal app using html. Is expected to work only on IE and CHROME not in FF.

Comment: No? That will make `object` `undefined` in all browsers but IE.

Comment: I fix object indefined by getting the value using getAttribute.

Comment: What are you talking about? You can't get even `object.id`. That's where your code will stop. Just take a look at the console, you'll see an error: "Can't read property id of undefined" or something similar.

Comment: if object is undefined ... trying to invoke `object.getAttribute()` will throw

Comment: [*"Inline event handlers such as this should be avoided.
In the same way that inline CSS styles are frowned upon ... inline event handlers
should be stripped out and replaced with events attached unobtrusively
through the DOM."*](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/onclick-html-attribute/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use an onclick event in an element, far easier to do this

```
<input onclick="dosomething(this);" />
```

Then your code can do

```
function dosomething(element) {
    // element is the element that was clicked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i done with this:

```
<html>

<body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]" id="pepe" class='chk' iffalse="N" iftrue="Y" value="0" onchange="validate()" />
    <br/> Value sent
    <input type="text" id="1234" value="" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var inputcb = document.getElementById('1234');

        function validate() {
            if (document.getElementById('pepe').checked) {
                inputcb.value = document.getElementById('pepe').getAttribute("iftrue");
            } else {
                inputcb.value = document.getElementById('pepe').getAttribute("iffalse");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```